# Roland 808 via MIDI trouble with tone playing

Tags: midi, cubase

I had a project in cubase that I recorded to audio file and everything was working fine a few days ago. Now when I open it again and play it in cubase the kick drum from the Roland 808 doesn't play (tone C1) and the tom tom plays instead (tone C#1) from the MIDI. I don't understand how this has happened. Do you have a theory what I should do to get back to the right setting?

It is strange that the MIDI track actually says C#1 which is tom tom and that is played, but previously the kick drum played. It looks like the MIDI drum pattern that I import is arranged correctly for the hi-hats but not for the kick drum. Still it worked the other day when I tried and I also recorded the kick drum where it now plays a C#1 tom tom. I assume that kick drum should be the C1 tone and therefore it seems unlikely that I have transposed it, the question is how I could have recorded the kick drum before without transposing. I'm confused how it can be done.

I've temporarily transposed the offending note from C#1 to C1 but this is probably not the right way to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally set up a Transpose in the inspector? Check play-through sends the correct note, which will narrow down your search area.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's strange and awkward because all my songs have lost the kick drum (C) and plays a tom tom (C#) instead and the original MIDI is also a C# for a kick drum. So it seems that something unlikely happened with the drum machines but that is impossible.

Comment: If all songs are affected, this must be a global setting (in Cubase, or in the 808).

Comment: @CL. I don't understand what that could be. All projects are affected. Where it previously played a kick drum, it now plays a tom tom. The note is C# where there now is a tom tom. The original MIDI file still has C# for the kick drum if I try and start over. I have no knowledge about any "global setting" and the MIDI file includes several other sounds from the 808 that are right in the same file. Can way explain why this is happening?

Comment: The Roland TR-808 does not have a MIDI input. What is the actual synthesizer you're using?

Comment: @CL. I use the actual Roland TR-808 with e a midi dcb converter that makes the 808 play MIDI from cubase. Now it seems that the note C1 plays the kick but it wasn't like this before. I can get the kick sound if I transpose the C#1 note manually but why did it even work before?

Comment: And what is the MIDI-to-DCB converter device you're using? How did you configure it?

Comment: @CL. Kenton Pro-Kadi MIDI converter at MIDI6, channel 16. All sounds play from cubase but the kick drum has mysteriously moved from C#1 to C1. I'm desperately looking around cubase to see what has happened. I didn't touch the 808 when this happened.

Comment: What is "MIDI6"? The sixth output of the Pro Kadi? What note number is it configured for?

Comment: @CL. I have a USB MIDI interface with 8 channels and 16 sub-channels. The 808 converter is default on MIDI number 6 and channel 16. If I transpose the C#1 to C1 then everything is fine, but I didn't have to transpose it previously so that is very strange that I suddenly must transpose something old.

Comment: Which of the Kadi's thirteen outputs is the kick drum connected to? What is the note number that the Kadi is configured to use for that output?

Comment: @CL. It is a completely default connection that used to work perfectly out of the box. It says 0 on one display and 16 on the other display on the Kadi. It has MIDI input that is connected to the MIDI interface. It has an output that is connected to the TR-808. I believe that I checked every possible setting. Worst case I can transpose this single note but it worked before without transposing. Something must have changed but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of your MIDI-to-DCB converter was changed, either by pressing the "Dec" button at the wrong time, or by cosmic radiation flipping the wrong bit.

To get the old configuration back, restore the device to the factory defaults (see the manual).

Comment: I found the manual here http://www.kentonuk.com/kmanualspdf/prokadiman.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As Tetsujin and CL told you in the comment, a transpose is apparently setted.
What you can do is:

1. Check all MIDI settings in CUBASE and look if you see a knob/input text field or other in relation with transposition setted to +1.
2. Check if your notes inside your MIDI pattern are the ones you wanted to record.
3. Check in your operating system's MIDI Settings if you added a +1 transpose somewhere.
4. Check in your 808 if you added a transpose option.
5. Check in your 808 if your Kick is still apparented to C note and Tom to C#.

Best of luck,

Comment: But it's so strange that the MIDI track actually says C#1 which is tom tom and that is played, but previously the kick drum played. It looks like the MIDI drum pattern that I import is arranged correctly for the hi-hats but not for the kick drum. Still it worked the other day when I tried and I also recorded the kick drum where it now plays a C#1 tom tom. I assume that kick drum _should_ be the C1 tone and therefore it seems unlikely that I have transposed it, the question is how I could have recorded the kick drum before without transposing. I'm confused how it can be done.

Comment: I've added one other possibility as an edit

Comment: Did you solved your problem?